# How do I calculate the current, voltage, and impedance that the input in this schema will receive?

Tags: impedance-matching

Can someone please show me how to calculate the current, voltage, and impedance that the LineLevelInput will receive?

In the schematic below:

- The left-side of the schematic represents the source of the signal, and the right-side represents the destination.
- SpeakerOut represents the speaker output of a small tube amp.
- R1 represents a dummy load resistor for the small tube amp.
- The transformer has a 1:8.66 turns ratio and a 1:75 impedance ratio.
- LineLevelInput represents the line-level input of a larger power amp with an input impedance of 10kΩ.

I really appreciate your help. I am trying to build a little DIY impedance-matching box. Please don't worry about overloading the input -- I am just trying to understand how to do the current, voltage, and impedance calculations at this point. I read about Ohm's Law and Kirchoff's Circuit Laws so I have the puzzle pieces in my hands but I don't know how to put them together.

Many, many thanks for your very kind help!!

Sincerely,
Nickel

[image: Schematic]

Comment: What are you trying to do? An audio line-level input is voltage only, and needs very little power indeed.  Impedance matching is not required.

Comment: I think you are looking for ohm's law.

Comment: There is not enough information to calculate anything. Also, wattage consumed by a line level input is usually never needes for anything. For what purpose you need it? Also it makes little sense to step up the voltage. If the amplifier does put put say 1 Vrms which is 0.125W, the transformer steps up that voltage to 8.66 Vrms which is extremely high for a line level and may damage the line input. Also, line inputs don't need impedance matching so why do you want impedance conversion?

Comment: Apologies to everyone. I am so ignorant it is hard for me to even ask a meaningful question.

Comment: The underlying problem is this -- I have a very weak signal coming from the speaker output of a small tube amp that I want to convert to a line-level signal and feed into the line-level input of a larger power amp. When I use a store-bought converter box, the power-amp's input receives a very weak signal. I reason that the converter box is, by design, converting only a small fraction of the power from the speaker out to line level.

Comment: So, my first goal is to **understand** the question of how would I convert the maximum amount of the power coming from the speaker out to line-level, using only passive components. Please note, this first question is a theoretical question that initially I want to understand in its simplest form, so I don't mind simplifications of the theory that will enable me to understand the main issues and features of the problem and solution.

Comment: The small amp's speaker output (source) is 8 Ohms and a standard line-level output is between around 100 Ohms to 600 Ohms. Based on my intuition only, I reasoned that in order to maximize the amount of power converted to line-level, I should use a transformer to convert the signal's impedance, rather than a resistor. Similarly, based on intuition only, I reasoned that, in order to get a "louder" signal at the power amp's input, I should shoot for the 600 Ohms side of the acceptable range of impedance for line-level, rather than the 100 Ohms side.

Comment: However, converting the impedance of the signal is not the only requirement -- I must ensure that the source amp's speaker output sees a proper load of 8 Ohms. To do that, I added a resistive load across the source amp's speaker out.

Comment: Again, my initial goal is simply to *understand* how to maximize the amount of power from the source amp's speaker out being converted to line-level. Then, given that solution, I want to *understand* how much of that power (voltage and current) would be arriving at the power-amp's line input for some given amount of power being produced by the source-amp's speaker output.

Comment: For example, if the source amp's speaker out has a load resistor in parallel with the primary of a transformer, and the source amp's speaker out produces a certain voltage and current, how do I calculate the voltage and current seen in the transformer's secondary? Or, if I were to add a resistor in series in the primary, how would that affect the load seen by the source amp and how would it affect the voltage, current, and impedance coming out of the secondary?

Comment: All that said, the first question I have is: How do I convert the maximum amount of the power coming from the speaker-out of the source amp to line-level (using only passive components) while maintaining a proper load on the source amp?

Comment: The second question I have is: How do I perform the calculations necessary to obtain the characteristics (voltage, current, impedance) of the signal coming from the transformer's secondary? And, how would simple modifications to the schematic (for example, the addition of a resistor in series in the primary) affect characteristics of the signal coming out of the transformer's secondary?

Comment: Once I feel confident that I understand the problem reasonably well, I will turn my attention to the practical question: How should I actually design the impedance converter box?

Comment: Thanks again to everyone for your excellent ideas and analysis and for your very kind help.

Comment: @Nickel1234 The problem is, speaker output impedance will not be 8 ohms. It will be lower, ideally zero. It's just the speaker that's 8 ohms. And because the tube can't drive an 8 ohm load directly, there is a transformer, to convert the 8 ohm load into a higher impedance which the tube can drive. And line inputs don't work with power but voltage.

Comment: Thanks, Justme. That is really great information. So, based on that, can I conclude that I shouldn't be using a transformer if my intention is to get as "loud" a signal as possible being converted to line-level? (using passive components, only) My goal is to take the very weak signal coming from the source-amp's speaker out and convert it to line-level in such a way that I maximize the power being transferred to the line-input of the power amp.

Comment: Amplifiers with tubes and audio transformers were used 70 years ago. Use a modern solid state amplifier today to replace them.

Comment: It is a guitar amp. Solid state guitar amps sound terrible.